# Get an Object at runtime which calls a specific method using javassist

Tags: java, aspectj, javassist

Is there anything in javassist which can replace this JoinPoint.getTarget()(AspectJ).
I am trying to fetch either the existing Object of a Class at runtime or fetch the specific Object which calls a specific method
For e.x

```
Class B
 {
    psvm()
    { //A is an existing class
       A a=new A();
       a.display();
/* i want to fetch a (object that calls method display) or the object of A (which can call method display) using javassist*/
     }
 }
```

Is it possible doing that in javassist.

Comment: what do you mean by fetch? Specify your question

Comment: I think it would be wise to describe what you actually want to achieve and for what reason. Maybe you can just fix your application or aspect code. Mixing AspectJ with Javassist sounds like a very ugly hack. Describe the problem (with code!), not how you think it should be solved.

Comment: @kriegaex i dont want to mix aspect with javassit. But i want that funtionality to be done by my Javassist agent.

Comment: @rakwaht i want to add some more functionalities at runtime.. Lets say adding custom header to a http request at runtime using javassist.

Comment: You want to emulate a subset of AspectJ features in your own Javassist agent? I really don't get it because you do not describe it particularly  well. BTW, why do you not just use AspectJ directly? It is stable, well-tested, enterprise-ready and has a nice syntax to describe what should be done. What does your agent do that you cannot do in AspectJ?

Comment: @kriegaex My requirement is to add headers to a http request at runtime.

Comment: But the thing is i need to modify an alrdy existing javassist agent so , i m trying to do that with javassist instead of AspectJ.

Comment: Okay, then I am out of the game, I know too little about Javassist. Too bad, it sounds like the perfect AspectJ use case.